# Why describe and fdescribe give the different result?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, google-maps, karma-jasmine, google-places-autocomplete

While writing unit tests for an Angular project using Karma and Jasmine, I met a weird issue.
When I test only a component using `fdescribe` it says `SUCCESS`.
But if I replace 'fdescribe' with 'describe' and check all tests work fine, then it throws an error for the above component.

The said component uses Google Maps feature, so I added a mock to `karma.config.js` like this.

```js
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    // ... other settings

    files: ['src/testing/google-map-mock.js'],   <-- added this for google maps
    // goes next settings
  });
};
```

After added the mockup, it worked with `fdescribe`, but still doesn't work with `describe`. So weird. Does anyone have any idea? I think the problem comes from between karma config and jasmine, with `fdescribe', the mock file is injected exactly, but with` describe` it's not. I think this is the problem.
Please help me if anyone have any idea for me.

Thank you!

I added a [mock](https://github.com/prasathmani/google-maps-mock-api/blob/master/gmaps.mock.api.js) to solve [google is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25225551/9644424) error.
After adding the mock, the component test works with `fdescribe`, but doesn't work with `describe` clause.

Comment: Please post code.

Comment: Very likely you have some form of state persisting between your individual tests. When you run with `fdescribe`, no other test touches the shared state (maybe your google map mock?). When you run with `describe`, some other test alters that shared state, which causes your specific test to fail.

Comment: [wlf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1188074/wlf), that makes sense, I will check if there's another google maps mock for other tests.